# Setting the key on an Index for a Blob field using Doctrine2 annotations in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can currently setup any indexes I might need on a table using annotations in Symfony2 and Doctrine2, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add a key to the index if I want to use a Blob.

I am using the example from the documentation:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",indexes={@index(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
```

The problem with this is that I can't use Blob field types as I can't seem to set the length of the key.

In MySql you would use something like "name(100)", but this doesn't work in the annotations above.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't see much point in setting `blob` as key because it can be very long...

Comment: I understand your point, but indexing a Blob still has it's uses as you can easily index the first section of the text. If it is a field holding general and random descriptions then it is no good, but I am using it quite specifically. It is something that is very possible and easily done in MySql. If it can't be done it can't be done, but hopefully someone will know.

Comment: Hi @ThomasK, no unfortunately not. It is just not supported. I just don't index my blob fields now. I find Symfony2 is quick enough in general to negate this anyway, but it is a shame it is not supported.

Comment: That's a shame. I set the index manually, but kept the annotation. As long as the index is there in the DB, doctrine won't complain. But when it's not there, the error serves as a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket in Jira http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2802

And they are not going to fix this.

Comment: Issue was closed with resolution "Won't Fix"

Comment: @Rooster242: yes, I know. that's why I wrote `they are not going to fix this`